# How to change the base fields label in openerp 6.1

Tags: odoo

researchorial but indeed i have done all the google around what i want o achieve in openerp that how to change those fields label ,i don't wanna play with fields and i know how to create new fields but what about base fields i am not able to edit them they throw some error that you cannot change the base fields from here so objective is clear that those label like Company, SSNID in hr module i want them changed according to them nothing else!!

please do not post links of already same question cause they had not been answered !!

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create New Hr employee Inherited view By this way.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="updated_hr_form_view">
<field name="name">updated.hr.form</field>
<field name="model">hr.employee</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
    <xpath expr="//form/notebook/page[@string='Personal Information'/group/field[@name='ssnid']]" position="replace">
        <field name="ssnid" string="Your New Label"/>
        </xpath>
</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the label of a field in two ways.

**1. Python code**

Inherit the  model where that field is defined, then inside _columns add the same field name with new label.
For example, if you want to change SSNID to Employee ID, assume that in the base module the field is defined as 'ssnid' and the field is in hr.employee model.

```
from osv import osv, fields
class hr_employee(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'
    _columns = {'ssnid': fields.integer('Employee ID')
    }
hr_employee()
```

**2. XML code(change the view)**

Inherit your view and add the attribute for the field 'ssnid'. For example in base module the field view is like `<field name="ssnid"/>` .To change it inherit its corresponding form and tree view and you can change the field by using `position="attribute"` and also position="replace". Add the attribute string="Employee ID".

```
<field name="ssnid" position="replace"> 
    <field name="ssnid" string="Employee ID"/>
</field>
```

Comment: Hey what if i wanted to replace in the core would it effect the reliability of software

Comment: It will not effect the reliability of the software. But i will not recommend to do that

Comment: I recommend the solution of changing the python code.  The reason is that it will change the string in all views: form, tree, search and other places such as export/import.  If you change the xml, you will not be able to change it everywhere.